# Group collection into collection of collections by key value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, collections, group-by

I have a collection of items like below:

```
[
    { Number: 1, Description: "Example description 1"},
    { Number: 1, Description: "Example description 2"},
    { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 3"},
    { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 4"}
]
```

I would like to group it by `Number` property to get next result:

```
[
    [
        { Number: 1, Description: "Example description 1"},
        { Number: 1, Description: "Example description 2"}
    ]
    [
        { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 3"},
        { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 4"}
    ]
]
```

Next function almost works for me:

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {

      return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
            (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
            return rv;
      }, {});
}
```

but it returns object with properties, where every property is an array. This prevents me from using `map` function on it.

How can I overcome this to get an array of arrays to be able to use `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use `reduce` function which allows you to iterate through the result. Then you can create create array in a loop:

```
var groupedMap = function(collection, key) { 
      var result = collection.reduce(
      (entryMap, e) => entryMap.set(e[key], [...entryMap.get(e[key])||[], e]),
      new Map());

      var resultArray = [];
      result.forEach(element => {
            resultArray.push(element);
      });

      return resultArray;
}
```

Example usage of this method for your case would be:

```
var arrayOfArray = groupedMap(exampleArray, 'Number');
```

Now you can call map function on `arrayOfArray`.
Note that this solution will won't work on `IE11` as it is compliant with the `ES6`.

Answer (score 3):

You could get the values from the object.

```js
const
    groupBy = function(xs, key) {
        return Object.values(xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
            (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
            return rv;
        }, {}));
    },
    data = [{ Number: 1, Description: "Example description 1" }, { Number: 1, Description: "Example description 2" }, { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 3" }, { Number: 2, Description: "Example description 4" }];
    
console.log(groupBy(data, 'Number'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```